# NoMethodError in Stories#index, undefined method 'each'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have looked over other posts but I have not understood what the problem is. Is there a problem with my show method? I am following a tutorial and he has left it blank.

Index.html.erb

```
<% page_header "Our cool stories" %>

<p><%= link_to 'Tell one!', new_story_path, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-large' %></p>

<% @stories.each do |stories| %>
  <div class="well well-lg">
    <h2><%= link_to story.title, story_path(story) %></h2>

    <p><%= truncate(story.body, length: 350) %></p>

    <div class="btn-group">
      <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_story_path(story), class: 'btn btn-info' %>
      <%= link_to 'Delete', story_path(story), data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

my stories controller:

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_story, only: [:destroy, :show, :edit, :update]
end

def index
    @stories = Story.order('created_at DESC')
end

def new
    @story = Story.new
end

def create
    @story = Story.new(story_params)
    if @story.save
        flash[:success] = "Your beautiful story has been added!"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
end

def update
    if @story.update.attributes(story_params)
        flash[:success] = "More knowledge, more wisdom"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    if @story.destroy
        flash[:success] = "I think you should have more confidence in your storytelling"
    else
        flash[:error] = "Can't delete this story, sorry"
    end

def show
    @stories = Story.all
end

private

def story_params
    params.require(:story).permit(:title, :body)
end

def find_story
    @story = Story.find(params[:id])
end
```

end

Error:

```
NoMethodError in Stories#index

Showing /home/benjamin/Desktop/oxygen/app/views/stories/index.html.erb where line #5 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #5):


    <p><%= link_to 'Tell one!', new_story_path, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-large' %></p>

    <% @stories.each do |stories| %>
      <div class="well well-lg">
        <h2><%= link_to story.title, story_path(story) %></h2>

I also receive this error in my terminal:

     ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
        2: 
        3: <p><%= link_to 'Tell one!', new_story_path, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-large' %></p>
        4: 
        5: <% @stories.each do |stories| %>
        6:   <div class="well well-lg">
        7:     <h2><%= link_to story.title, story_path(story) %></h2>
        8:
```

Comment: in line5 the @stories is nil

Comment: What is the endpoint that results in this error?

Also you have @stories.each do |stories|

Typicaly this would be: do |story| (remove pluralization)

Comment: Post the rails server log of the error. Including the url, params, exception and everything.

Comment: Is this a template for `index` or for `show`?

Comment: @whodini9: note that he _does_ have `@stories = Story.all` in the show action

Comment: Sorry, it's a template for the index.html.erb, I'll edit above.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Right, but as he just mentioned, he is rendering index.html.erb. I've done this mistake many times :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class StoriesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_story, only: [:destroy, :show, :edit, :update]
end  # <--- this `end` breaks everything
```

You end your controller definition very soon. Therefore, it doesn't have any action methods defined (which means no `@stories` for you).

All those methods should go **into** controller, not sit outside.

Comment: @jan: _technically_, that `end` breaks nothing. :)